# On page check-out not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Magento 1.9 here, moved website from one hosting to another, now checkout is not working properly. After billing info, when I click "continue" it won't show me shipping info form.
I tried all solution i found in previous answer, but wasn't able to solve. No Javascript errors.
Another problem is that when i click on "Add to cart" button product is added but the waiting wheel doesn't disappear

Can you help ? Here's the website https://www.centocaffe.com/
Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1):

I think,
I am trying the add to cart but not appear and after reload the page and showing product in minicart.
I am find the some solution in your case.This issues is your not import ya export right database.

Your get the any error in database import or export time ??
because i am asking this question so i have try the add to cart and reload the page and showing the product in minicart but i am remove the product and live site redirected the another site.
Please Check Video :- https://www.loom.com/share/a1f0f14a97004c70ba6796698ebb9927
This issue is add to cart successfully but not respond right hosting.So showing the loading.

[image]

Finally you import the database is wrong.So Import the right database and add the links in core_config table and after check

Hope it will work

Thanks.

Comment: Helllo @dan this answer you helpful So Please accept the answer